# How to detect file mime by file header on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, web, server, content-type, libmagic

I want to return a file stored without extension name.
But nginx returns it with `application/octet-stream`.

I want return a file with correct mime, **based on file header but not extension name**, like using `file --mime-type -b <filename>`

How should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by file header? - please edit your question and give an example.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15571975/1264360